# Convert template<typename ...Ts> into std::tuple<something<T>>

Tags: c++, stdtuple

Suppose `abc` is defined as:

```
template <typename T>
struct abc;
```

and `xyz` as

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct xyz;
```

Is it possible to declare an attribute in `xyz` such as `std::tuple<abc<T>>` for each `T` in `Ts`?

Comment: If you want to pluck out just one of the `Ts` and then turn it into a `std::tuple<abc<T>>`, you can use `std::tuple_element`: `template<int N> using xyz = std::tuple<abc<std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>>>;` It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. Can you give an example usage of the thing you want?

Comment: @RaymondChen, below is the answer and an example to illustrate

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using `std::tuple<abc<Ts>...>`, as the example below ilustrates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template <typename t> struct abc {
  abc() = default;
  abc(int p) : i(p) {}
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const abc &x) {
    out << x.i;
    return out;
  }
  int i;
};

template <typename... ts> struct xyz {
  template <typename t> void add(int i) {
    std::get<abc<t>>(m_tuple) = abc<t>(i);
  }

  template <typename t> void print() {
    cout << std::get<abc<t>>(m_tuple) << endl;
  }

  using tuples = std::tuple<ts...>;
  typedef std::tuple<abc<ts>...> tuple;
  tuple m_tuple;
};

struct a {};

struct b {};

struct c {};

int main() {
  using v = xyz<a, b, c>;

  v v0;

  v0.add<a>(-9);
  v0.add<b>(22);
  v0.add<c>(-235);

  v0.print<a>();
  v0.print<b>();
  v0.print<c>();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I simplified the code by using `std::get<t>` directly. (Also, this doesn't seem to match your question. Your question as stated asked for std::tuple<abc<T>> for each T in Ts, so I assume that given xyz<a, b, c> you would have three types, std::tuple<abc<a>>, std::tuple<abc<b>>, and std::tuple<abc<c>>. Your solution has a single type std::tuple<abc<Ts>...>. Maybe you can rephrase your question so it matches your solution. Also C++ doesn't have attributes, so maybe you meant "function" or "type alias"?)

Comment: I appreciate very much your contribution, it really is much simpler and better than mine, but it seems odd to me that Stack Overflow allows a user to modify other user posts. IMHO, it would make sense the modification to be in another post, not only to preserve the original post from the first user, but so that anyone that reads this thread sees the evolution of the solution. Does that make sense?